# When and why did Worf return to Starfleet duty?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-ds9, worf

In *DS9* s6e11 "[Waltz](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Waltz_(episode))", Worf is back on duty as a Starfleet officer.   Last I remember,  he was serving as first officer of the IKS Rotarran.  I guess I wasn't paying attention.

## When and why did Worf return to Starfleet duty?

Comment: He never left Starfleet - he was on secondment

Comment: @HorusKol, I know.   That answers "how".   What were the circumstances?  Did I miss something about the Rotarran  or Martok?  Or was it just triggered by the retaking of DS9?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Worf's service aboard the IKS Rotarran is discussed in DS9: [Soldiers of the Empire.](http://www.st-minutiae.com/resources/scripts/519.txt) In short, he's on a *temporary* assignment.

> **SISKO:** *As of this moment you will be relieved of all Starfleet obligations and will be placed on detached service to the Imperial
>   Klingon Defense Forces.*

This is a [real-world military term](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=B2jDGUK08NAC&pg=PA286&lpg=PA286&dq=%22on+detached+service%22&source=bl&ots=PMWKEuHsgI&sig=5H2LPXvcEx-tDOAjKD0p-Kai6nk&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22on%20detached%20service%22&f=false) that means "*serving away from one's assigned unit or company without being formally transferred*"

---

As to why/when he returned, both Martok and Sisko make it abundantly clear that he's being released for the duration of the mission only, not as a semi-permanent assignment. Presumably once the mission was over, he came back to DS9 (along with Dax) by the most expeditious route:

> **Martok:** *Worf, son of Mogh... **I ask you to join me on this mission** as my friend... and as my first officer.*

and

> **MARTOK:** *Your tone does not sit well with me, helmsman. **Our mission is to find the B'Moth,** not satisfy your warrior's pride.*

and

> **SISKO:** *I told the General I'm inclined to grant his request for your services, commander. I can certainly understand why he'd want you along -- you're a fine officer. **But I'm not sure why you want to go on this mission.***

Comment: I'm asking about the circumstances of the end of that assignment.   Was there any dialog,  or he just suddenly aspirated back in Starfleet uniform?

Comment: @ThePopMachine - He just turned up two episodes later. I'm guessing that in the intervening episode, he and Dax were making their way back to DS9.

Comment: Aspirated->appeared  swypo

Comment: Okay,  good answer.